# AMQP Content header payload structure

Tags: amqp

I try to implement yet another amqp-client (on C++, heavily integrated with our base frameworks). And I've come to the point of interpreting the content header payload, and I cannot find clear description of the relationship between property-flags and property-list. If I got F1%b1,F2%b1, ... ,Fn%b0 in property-flags, what *amqp-field sequence I MUST expect in property-list?

Can anyone, please, point me on any doc where I can find this information?

Answer (score 4):

I realize that this is an old post, but since I recently came upon some enlightement on this topic, I'll post my observations here in case others have a need to understand this detail.

I just recently fought this battle while trying to implement the AMQP API for Perl in order to talk to a RabbitMQ server. I also did not find any official documentation regarding this detail. However, the rabbitmq docs have among them the source code for a JAVA API.

```
http://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html
```

Buried in all of that source code is a python utility that generates the low level frame construction code.

So, some background - The properties are attributes that may be attached to messages that wind up in queues. These are not arbitrary attributes, but rather have specific definitions. In particular, the properties are defined to be members of the BASIC class (ie. class # 60). The BASIC class is the only class that has properties. The properties appear at the tail end of the content header frames. Their specification comes in 2 parts:

- property flags
- property list

The property flags are used to specify which of the 14 properties are documented in the property list. These are encoded as individual bits in the property flags. The BASIC class definition lists the properties in order (see: http://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.xml) , and it is in that order that they are referenced in the property flags. Thus, the property flags octets:

```
00010000 01000000 (0x 10 40)
```

reference 2 of the 14 properties: "delivery-mode" and "timestamp". If all of the bits in the flags are "0", that signifies that NO properties are referenced.

So then for the property list, the delivery-mode property is encoded first, followed by the timestamp. The delivery-mode is specified as a single octet, and the timestamp is specified as "long-long-uint", or an 8 octet network encoded (ie. big endian) integer.
According to that code, the property list bytes are built according to which of the property flags are set. Thus, if no property flags are set - ie. all are "0", no property list bytes are part of the header frame. So then, assembling these:

```
10 40 01 00 00 00 00 53 3B 2B 47
^ flags     
      ^ delivery-mode (1 = non-persistent)
         ^ timestamp (1396386631 (unix epoch) = Tue Apr  1 15:10:31 2014)
```

Comment: You're the saviour! 5 years later the docs are still as obscure. Thanks.